# Como mostrar o número de repetições MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um banco no qual são cadastrado nomes e sobrenome, eu consigo agrupar os resultados da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usuarios GROUP BY sobrenome
```

Então, se tiver *80 registros* repetidos do sobrenome **"José"** por exemplo, obviamente ele agrupa e mostra apenas 1 "José", mas eu quero além de agrupar os nomes, quero contar quais são os 5 sobrenomes mais repetidos da tabela, ou seja, *mesmo tendo mais de 30  sobrenomes repetidos* por exemplo, eu quero mostrar apenas os 5 mais repetidos, ou seja, os *5 sobrenomes mais comum na tabela*.
Existe algum meio de fazer isto direto no MySQL ou preciso criar algum script no PHP?

Comment: Então seria outro SQL para trazer os 5 mais repetidos, certo?

Comment: Exato! seria ideal outro SQL pra trazer os 5 mais repetidos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faz um SQL dessa forma. Coloque `limit 2` no final para ficar mais fácil de montar o fiddle. No seu caso usa `limit 5`.

```
select n.sobrenome, count(*) from nomes n
group by n.sobrenome
order by count(*) desc
limit 2
```

SQL rodando nesse [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b627/3)

Código de montagem do banco de dados no Fiddle, colocando aqui para registrar.

```
create table nomes(
  id varchar(10),
  nome varchar(40),
  sobrenome varchar(40),
  endereco varchar(40));

  insert into nomes values(
    "1","ricardo","chaves","endereco ricardo");

      insert into nomes values(
    "2","daniel","chaves","endereco daniel");

      insert into nomes values(
    "3","maria","madalena","endereco maria");

      insert into nomes values(
    "4","felipe","geraldo","endereco geraldo");

      insert into nomes values(
    "5","jose","geraldo","endereco jose");

      insert into nomes values(
    "6","jose","madalena","endereco jose1");

    insert into nomes values(
    "6","Maria2","madalena","endereco maria2");
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Pegando somente a data atual, considerando que a coluna `date` é a data do cadastro:

```
    select n.sobrenome, data, count(*) 
      from usuarios n 
     where n.date = (data atual)
  group by n.sobrenome order by count(*) 
desc limit 5
```

Comment: Muito bom Ricardo, ajudou muito. Obrigado

Comment: Ricardo, e se eu quiser mostrar os 5 resultados dos sobrenomes mais cadastrados na data atual, tipo, de todo o BD, João é o mais repetido, mas e se eu quiser mostrar os repetidos apenas da data atual? ou seja, os 5 mais comum registrados hoje?
Meu código está assim: `select n.sobrenome, data, count(*) from usuarios n group by n.sobrenome order by count(*) desc limit 5 ` tentei incluir o  `date desc` no group by, mas não funciona, ele ordena por data. tem alguma forma de buscar os dados apenas da data atual?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Quando é assim seria legal fazer outra pergunta, porque caso eu demore a ler o comentário outras pessoas não vão te ajudar, uma nova pergunta vai aparecer para todos os usuários.

Comment: Obrigado! deu certo.